# Organizing API data with Python

Tags: python, json, api, formatting

I'm using a python script to call an API - for some reason the data coming in isn't presented JSON format (I tried to use jQuery, but I don't think the data is stored in JSON), so I'm unable to use json.loads()/Panda. The data I'm getting is coming in like this, with no line separation.

> key,reputation,prevent execution,comment,remove\r\ncoronavirus.app,whitelist,false,null,false\r\ne-1.claudioboxx.com,whitelist,false,null,false\r\ne-3.claudioboxx.com,whitelist,false,null,false

Ideally I'd like to format the data in a table where it's easier to read, or to find a way to format in JSON so I can use panda. Any tips are appreciated!

It'd like to be able to store the results as

```
key = ncoronavirus.app, ne-1.claudioboxx.com, ne-3.claudiobox.com
reputation = whitelist, whitelist, whitelist
etc..
```

so that I can display them in an easier to read table.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a csv string.  To parse it into `pandas` data frame, you can use `pandas.read_csv` as below (If you are on Python 2, replace the first line with `from StringIO import StringIO`).

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
x = """key,reputation,prevent execution,comment,remove\r\ncoronavirus.app,whitelist,false,null,false\r\ne-1.claudioboxx.com,whitelist,false,null,false\r\ne-3.claudioboxx.com,whitelist,false,null,false"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(x))
```

```py
print(df)

                   key reputation  prevent execution  comment  remove
0      coronavirus.app  whitelist              False      NaN   False
1  e-1.claudioboxx.com  whitelist              False      NaN   False
2  e-3.claudioboxx.com  whitelist              False      NaN   False
```

Comment: This looks promising! Another stupid question, the file starts with a byte b', how should I strip that before putting it through the last function?